# AJAX-altering JS gives JS variable inside an event function after the function is finished

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following PHP file that I will call using my `$.ajax()` in my JS:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('One' => 'Test'));
?>
```

And I have the following code in my JS:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    let changeValue;
    $('#someElementID').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'phpfile.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function(obj, textStatus) {
                changeValue = obj.One;
            }
        });

        $('#toBeChangedElementValue').text(changeValue);
    }
</script>
```

Problem is: the `changeValue` variable only gets its value after my `$('#toBeChangedElementValue').text()` has been executed. How does it work? How do I fix this? I had to place `$('#toBeChangedElementValue').text(changeValue)` in my success callback instead to make it work. Why didn't my `changeValue` get updated first before that final `.text()` happened?

Comment: Put `$('#toBeChangedElementValue').text(obj.One);` inside the success callback? There are other ways to do this (with `await` for instance), but this is the most "traditional" way to deal with async code.

Comment: @Jeto Yeah, I did figure that out. I'm just curious why doesn't my `changeValue` value assignment happen first.

Comment: Because [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is asynchronous. Code following it will execute right away, and the callbacks will be called only when the result/error is ready. You can use `const result = await $.ajax(...)` as an alternative (modern JS, so might not be compatible with older browsers if you don't use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)).

Comment: @Jeto I see. Thank you. Can I ask you some other questions that are not related to this current question?

Comment: Please create other questions instead. I'll vote this one as duplicate as I finally found the related question I was thinking about.

Comment: @Jeto The 90-min restriction is pretty bothersome, though.

Comment: @WealthyPlayer — Spend the time researching the problem instead.